# Python 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm playing around with Python and listening for UDP packets on a given port, everything seems to be working nicely - but after an extended period of time the script crashes with the following error:

```
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

When restarting just the script, the same crash occurs again after a shorter period of time. Restarting the server instead seems to resolve the problem completely for a while again.

With respect to the socket side of things, I'm doing:

```
UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 6000

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind( (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT) )
```

Am I missing something obvious or is there just a simple way of avoiding this?

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed!

Benji

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error "Connection reset by peer" on a UDP socket, means the client has received an ICMP error message (for example: port unreachable, TTL exceeded, etc.) from the server on a packet it has sent.

I can't say for sure what is causing this in your code, but I can offer two ideas:

1. The connection was really interrupted by something (routing problem, server side failure, etc.). In this case, you can check for this error, and if and when it occurs you can reopen your socket.
2. What seems more probable to me, but I'm less familiar with, is that `SO_REUSEADDR` is causing the problem. This socket option lets you open multiple sockets on the same port. What **possibly** happens, is that some other process is trying to use port 6000, succeeds (because you tell the OS not to block it), and your socket is closed by the OS. Since I don't see a reason to use `SO_REUSEADDR` on UDP sockets, I would suggest you remove the line `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` and try again.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most relevant but I had the same ErrNo54 or ErrNo104 Connection Reset by peer error while trying to send a HTTP GET request (using the Python socket) to the DNS (DoH) resolver.

I resolved it by fixing the parameters in my HTTP request. For my instance, I initially had a Content-Type: application/dns-message which I later changed to Accept: application/dns-message.

Hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar issue.